# Passing argument to a function

Tags: c++, coding-style

Is it a bad programming principle to pass arg to a function which isn't "exact match" type wise but has trivial or user defined conversion to this type? For example:

```
void f(bool option);
```

and later in main (this is highly hypothetical so please don't give advise on that code):

```
int a = getSomeValue();

f(a);//here instead of bool I'm passing int - is it a bad programming practice or not?
```

Comment: depends on context. Are we talking about this situation then you may get an answer. But if you are talking in general then the question is way to open(general) to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on context.

In this very specific situation that you site in your question. I prefer the explicit test rather than than the implicit conversion of 0 to false (But that is also because the names of the variables and the function are so meaningless if they were named differently then I may not mind).

But there are other situations were the implicit conversion is fine:

```
std::ifstream f("File");
if (f) 
{
    // Testing f is relatively standard.
}
```

Any time there is information loss. I would expect an explicit cast with a comment explaining why the information loss is OK.

```
long theDistanceToLodond = getDistance("ToLondon");
InsideM25Action(static_cast<short>(theDistanceToLondon)); // All distances inside the M25 fit in a short therefore no information loss.
```

But casts where no information is lost should not have an explicit cast (it over-crowds the code without providing any benifit).I would not expect explicit down casts of pointers towards the base class etc.

Comment: that exactly what I had in mind(when having little quarrel with my tutor who is very adamant that this is always a bad practice), that is, that sometimes it is just a almost convention (like in your example with stream) and sometimes it is even better than explicit cast (no code cluttering).

Comment: @There: be wary of tutors, they might have Computer Science Principles which make them disapprove of weak typing and implicit conversion in favour of absolute strong typing. The more you care about type as an academic thing (as opposed to the numeric values that are your actual data), the more likely you are to think that conversion from `short` to `long` should be lit up in neon. Not because it might cause bugs (which is what we mostly care about on SO), but because changing the type changes everything, fundamentally. They'd say that `1`, `1l`, `1.0` and `1.0f` are all incommensurate.

Comment: Now, in a language designed to be strongly-typed and that forbids you from writing `1.0 + 1`, that might be fair enough, and there are genuine benefits to a language like that in terms of avoiding certain kinds of bug. But C++ has (limited) weak typing, and it will just let you compare and convert all those values regardless of what you think should happen and regardless of whether you try (and perhaps fail) to explicitly cast everywhere. So as practical programmers we'd mostly rather run with that, than try to impose concepts and principles that the language actively disagrees with.

Answer (score 6):

I think most people will consider this bad practice. Writing `f(a !=0)` is much clearer and expresses the intent concisely.

Comment: I feel like you've ignored the question in favor of answering just the example.

Comment: Probably. But it's still some sort of a general statement: always go for a solution that won't confuse or delay you or other people reading the source. Some of the other responses have quite some good examples, I upvoted them.

Comment: @ Alexander Gessler: If you are answering the example your answer is correct. But if you are answering the general case (which is what the question is about) you are wrong. Its not always bad practice to allow auto-conversion.

Comment: I did not claim the opposite. It's always fine as long as nothing un-intuitive happens. Promoting int to bool, which has totally different semantics, *is* unintuitive (I think we all agree on that part). Led by the example, I tried to outline what I consider important for the decision whether a implicit conversion is fine or evil.

Answer (score 6):

Conversion to bool is a bit of a special case, because it doesn't behave like integer conversions, so a lot of people like to see it explicit, and done with `!= 0` rather than a cast.

If you're passing an `int` to a function that takes `long`, then I certainly wouldn't want to see that cluttered with any kind of explicit conversion. Similarly I wouldn't want to see `char*` cast to `const char*` in order to pass it to `strlen`. Those conversions "don't really do anything": they always preserve the value of the input, and in the case of the pointer it doesn't let you do anything with the referand that you couldn't do using the original pointer.

If you're passing an `unsigned long` to a function that takes `unsigned int`, then on some implementations (but by no means on all common ones), it's a "narrowing conversion" which depending on the values can discard information by taking a modulus. It's often a good idea to make the conversion explicit in such cases, so that the casual reader doesn't have to check the function signature to realise that it happens. These conversions "do something" that might be surprising.

The same goes when converting between integer and floating types: although `int -> double` is harmless on pretty much any implementation you'll ever see, `double -> int` has undefined behavior for some values, so you don't want a reader to miss it.

Sometimes however, quite complex user-defined conversions are provided specifically so that you can call a function and benefit from an implicit conversion. So for those, you should probably follow the usage examples in whatever API defined the conversion.

For example if `Foo` has an implicit constructor that takes a `std::string`, and some function `bar` takes a `Foo`, that's not a whole lot different from the POV of a caller of `bar` than if the API had provided only an explicit conversion but two overloads of `bar`, one taking `Foo` and one that takes `std::string` but converts it straight to `Foo` and calls the other. So relying on the conversion in a case like that is no worse than overloading a function. The latter is not regarded as the crime of the century. Except by Python programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think this is bad programming practice.

Relying on implicit conversions may lead to very strange errors.
I once had the following problem.
It all started with a function like this:

```
void doSomething (ClassX x, ClassY y, bool b);
```

This function was called with code like this:

```
ClassX x;
ClassY y;
doSomething (x, y, true);
```

Later, somebody decided that the arguments of doSomething had to be changed, since doSomething now also required an instance of ClassZ.  Also, the boolean argument was true in many cases, so it was changed into a default argument, like this:

```
void doSomething (ClassX x, ClassY y, ClassZ z, bool b=true);
```

Although most of the code was changed, the call shown before, wasn't changed.
Strange enough, ClassZ had a non-explicit constructor taking a bool as argument:

```
class ClassZ
   {
   public:
      ClassZ(bool b);
   };
```

What happened was the following.  This call:

```
ClassX x;
ClassY y;
doSomething (x, y, true);
```

Was silently transformed into this by the compiler:

```
ClassX x;
ClassY y;
doSomething (x, y, ClassZ(true), true);
```

With the 4th argument being the default true.

Years later, we found out that something didn't work correctly, and after a lot of debugging, we found out that this call was the cause of the problem.

Therefore:

- never rely on implicit conversions
- mark constructors with 1 argument as explicit
- try to avoid the use of default arguments

Comment: "Therefore:" write more tests? ;-p

Comment: @Steve, completely agree, but some things can still go unnoticed.  In this case, another construction hid this bug, and it was only years later, then this other construction was changed, that we found this strange effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `short` variable to `f(int)`, then it's fine. But the opposite is dangerous (i.e `int` to `short` -  **possible overflow!**), and most compilers wouldn't be happy and so would give you warnings.

As for `f(bool)`, so yes, the intent is more clear when you write `f(a!=0)` when calling `f`. Here we do it for the sake of readability, not that it's dangerous to pass simply `a` as `f(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++, you should have done:

```
   int a = getSomeValue();
   f(static_cast<bool>(a));
```

That will surely express what is your intention, that's why we have many types of explicit casts.

Comment: It has the same effect as the implicit conversion. Also you are not adding any more meaning to the code (ie you are not expressing what your intent is to the reader of the code). So in this situation I would consider the static_cast worse than no cast as it clutters the code. On the other hand a !=0 explicitly defined what you mean.

Comment: Yes, it has the same effect, but not the same expressiveness. Here you can say: f() receives a bool and I'm casting a from int to that bool. Anyway, that's a very subjective question.

Comment: `f(a != 0)` is much more meaningful / expressive than `static_cast<bool>`

Comment: As I said, it's a personal taste.